# How to install font with terminal command line?

Tags: linux, yum, fonts, pdf, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to install SimSun Font through the command line.

I am connected to aws with ssh. I don't know much about linux.

The reason I am trying to install this font is because a Pentaho report is not showing chinese characters in PDF when it goes through the server. Locally, it works because I have the font installed.

I've looked at the fonts in aws (command: fc-list) but those fonts don't work in pdf.

I'm stuck at command: sudo yum install….

i have a ttf file on my local but i'm not sure if i can copy and paste from my local to ec2

Answer (score 1):

`sudo yum groupinstall "Chinese Support"` should do the trick to install all missing fonts and configurations related to Chinese language on a Red Hat Based Distribution.

This should solve your issue with Chinese fonts.